# How to format not delimiter-separated values file?

Tags: python, bash, pandas, awk, sed

I have a txt like the following one.

```
  DATE                HOUR          LCU             MVS             ACTIVE        
                                    NUMBER          SYSTEM          RATE         
                                                    ID                           
  2017-04-03                    0            004D   PROD                  12.15  
  2017-04-03                    0            005F   PROD                   9.82  
  2017-04-03                    0            0060   PROD                   5.99
```

If the input is not csv, or tsv, or space-delimited, How can I put in columns the value and the header?

I tried sed, awk, Pandas, with no results.
No regulars patterns between different columns

I would like a file like this one:

```
 DATE                           HOUR         LCU    MVS             ACTIVE        
                                             NUMBER SYSTEM          RATE         
                                                    ID                           
  2017-04-03                    0            004D   PROD            12.15  
  2017-04-03                    0            005F   PROD            9.82  
  2017-04-03                    0            0060   PROD            5.99
```

UPDATE
It would be obviously great to transform it into a csv, but taking into consideration missing fields.

```
DATE,HOUR,LCU,MVS,ACTIVE    
,,NUMBER,SYSTEM,RATE        
,,,ID,                      
2017-04-03,0,004D,PROD,12.15
2017-04-03,0,005F,PROD,9.82 
2017-04-03,0,0060,PROD,5.99
```

Comment: Is it a mix of spaces and tabs?

Comment: What is this file? where has it come from? Its being delimited by something otherwise it would be a continuous string with no format at all.

2017-04-030004DPROD12.15  
2017-04-030005FPROD9.82
2017-04-0300060PROD5.99

based on the work to concatenate this, it's space delimited... unless you've just typed it in to look like the output.

Comment: kind of mix of spaces and tabs in the header, just spaces in the body

Comment: What do you mean "Put in columns the value and the header"?

Comment: @StevenDavison I am trying to process it as if it was a continuous string (one line=one string) but how?!

Comment: I think you'd have to interpret the file as if it were space delimited... thats the only way I can see you'll do anything.

Comment: @JNevill question updated, I hope it is clearer now

Comment: @StevenDavison Considering it as spaces delimited I am having big troubles with missing values or for example with the header...I will have NUMBER (the last words of the 3rd column's header) and ID under DATE

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "DATE,HOUR,LCU_NUMBER,MVS_SYSTEM_ID,ACTIVE_RATE" > out.csv
tail -n+4 file.txt | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' >> out.csv
```

Comment: It could work but I can't echo the first line as you did

Answer (score 0):

If you can manually add line 2 and 3, use below -

```
$ awk '(NR==1 || NR > 3) {printf "%-32s %-10s %-6s %-18s %-10s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
DATE                             HOUR       LCU    MVS                ACTIVE
2017-04-03                       0          004D   PROD               12.15
2017-04-03                       0          005F   PROD               9.82
2017-04-03                       0          0060   PROD               5.99
```

Comment: I can't, unfortunately it comes from an SQL query and I have just the output in the form I have written

Answer (score 0):

**Pandas solution**

Your file seems to be a fixed-width-format file, so we can use [Pandas.read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_fwf('/path/to/input_file.txt').to_csv('c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

Result (`'c:/temp/out.csv'`):

```
DATE,HOUR,LCU,MVS,ACTIVE
,,NUMBER,SYSTEM,RATE
,,,ID,
2017-04-03,0.0,004D,PROD,12.15
2017-04-03,0.0,005F,PROD,9.82
2017-04-03,0.0,0060,PROD,5.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data uses Fixed Width Fields and the way to handle that in GNU awk is just to specify the width of each field in the FIELDWIDTHS variable:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="12 21 16 9 21"; OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
DATE,HOUR,LCU,MVS,ACTIVE
,,NUMBER,SYSTEM,RATE
,,,ID,
2017-04-03,0,004D,PROD,12.15
2017-04-03,0,005F,PROD,9.82
2017-04-03,0,0060,PROD,5.99
```

This creates more useful CSV headers though:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="12 21 16 9 21"; OFS="," }
/[0-9]/ {
    if ( !inData++ ) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", hdr[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
        if ($i != "") {
            hdr[i] = (i in hdr ? hdr[i] "_" : "") $i
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
DATE,HOUR,LCU_NUMBER,MVS_SYSTEM_ID,ACTIVE_RATE
2017-04-03,0,004D,PROD,12.15
2017-04-03,0,005F,PROD,9.82
2017-04-03,0,0060,PROD,5.99
```

If your input actually has a mix of blank characters and tabs then run it through `pr -e -t` first to convert all tabs to their relative spacing with blanks.